# Ansible playbook that runs a script and fetch the outpot back to the playbook

Tags: ansible

im trying to run a playbook that will create a user and will add it to /etc/sudoers,
so i wrote this thing

```
    - hosts: "{{ hostname }}"
  vars_prompt:
    - name: user
      prompt: "Enter user"
      private: no
    - name: password
      prompt: "Enter password"

  tasks:
    - name: Create the new user
      user:
        name: "{{ user }}"
        state: present
        #state: absent
        password: "{{ password  | password_hash('sha512', 'password') }}"
        groups: SSHusers


    - name: Add line in /etc/sudoers
      lineinfile:
        dest: /etc/sudoers
        line: "User_Alias LINUX_ADMINS = Example, {{ user }}"
        regexp: "^User_Alias LINUX_ADMINS."
        state: present
        #state: absent
       

    - name: Run chage for user
      command: chage -d 9999999999 "{{ user }}"
    - name: Run chage for user
      command: chage -M -1 "{{ user }}"
```

the problem is that i replace the line in `- name: Add line in /etc/sudoers`
an the i have to change it every time i add a new user.

i need to run something like that on the host `Admin_Users=$(grep -w 'LINUX_ADMINS =' /etc/sudoers)` and bring the var back so that my playbook will be able to use it ,
any suggestion to how should i do it ?
thanks for the help

Comment: Define the couple of tasks `create user + add to sudoer` as [a role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html) or as an [include](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_module.html) to DRY your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to restructure your playbook.

- You still run the "user" task for each user.
- But you run the "lineinfile" task not for a single user but for all users together.

If you pass all users to "lineinfile", the task can craft the whole line at once. And so the problem to change the line incrementally for each user disappears.